# Display information in cell based on other cell value

Tags: excel, variables, row

I have a client list database on a excel document. What I need is to display client information by entering a number (each client has a code). For example, if I enter the number "1" it would have to show the info of number one client. I thought that I could do someshing like these:

The codes of the clients start at A1 cell, and the names at B1. On another part of the document (let's say on the cell G4), I enter a number, for example number 7. Then, I want the cell above to the "7" (G5) display the name of the client. To do it I thought to link the cell to the B column (where the names are) and the row that says the cell G4 (in that case G4=7). That would point to the right cell by entering a fixed column and a variable row. The problem is that I have no idea on how I could do these. I tried entering a formula like "=LINK(B(G4))" but this is not a correct formula. How these could be done? So many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use following formula in `G5`:

```
=VLOOKUP(G4,$A:$B,2,0)
```

If an exact match is not found, the error value `#N/A` is returned.
You can also modify formula to return `"not found"` (or another message) instead `#N/A`:

for excel 2007 or later:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G4,$A:$B,2,0),"not found")
```

for excel 2003:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(G4,$A:$B,2,0)), "not found", VLOOKUP(G4,$A:$B,2,0))
```

You can read more about VLOOKUP [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but I am getting wrong formula error

Comment: try to change separator in formula from `,` to `;` - `=VLOOKUP(G4;$A:$B;2;0)`